# Item number condition

Tags: python, pandas

I need to select specific item number from my data, and I am confused why sometimes I need to add ' ' to the number, and sometimes if I add it, it does not work. Does anyone knows why?

```
df=df[df['Item No']==955764730550)]

df=df[df['Item No']=='955764730550')]
```

Comment: "It does not work..." What does that mean? Do you get an error or an empty dataframe? You should read this doc and you'll probably be able to answer the question yourself- https://docs.python.org/3/library/datatypes.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If dtype is float then you will not need ' ', if it is string, you will need it, you can try something like :

```
df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True).dtypes
```